# nested list comprehension using intermediate result

Tags: python

I am trying to grok the output of a function which doesn't have the courtesy of setting a result code. I can tell it failed by the "error:" string which is mixed into the stderr stream, often in the middle of a different conversion status message.

I have the following list comprehension which works, but scans for the "error:" string twice. Since it is only rescanning the actual error lines, it works fine, but it annoys me I can't figure out how to use a single scan. Here's the working code:

```
errors = [e[e.find('error:'):] for e in err.splitlines() if 'error:' in e]
```

The obvious (and wrong) way to simplify is to save the "find" result

```
errors = [e[i:] for i in e.find('error:') if i != -1 for e in err.splitlines()]
```

However, I get "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment". Blindly reversing the 'for's in the comprehension also fails. How is this done?

THanks. Kent

Comment: first of all. why not regular for loop with something that looks as cute as this?

Comment: `errors = filter(None, (e.split('error:',1) + [None])[1] for e in err.splitlines())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the check for `'error'` inside a generator expression:

```
[e[i:] for i,e in
 ((e.find('error:'),e) for e in err.splitlines())
 if i != -1]
```

What you did was to create a nested comprehension and, by using the `e` variable before the second loop, you got the UnboundLocalError

BTW, you can also use regex and avoid this comprehension:

```
re.findall('error:(.*)', err)
```

No need to split lines also.

for the complete error (with the `error:` part) this works:

```
re.findall('error:.*', err)
```

Comment: This works, but it seems less easy to read than just writing a single generator function.

Comment: @Marcin I was just correcting the comprehension. The real answer is the simple regex which is better than a generator.

Comment: I have tried the first solution and in my example it wont work. Got only substrings of the last line instead of real error messages... I added my fixed version as the comments wont accept code...

Comment: @JBernardo, when I try the revised comprehension I get "NameError: global name 'e' is not defined". I assume that's because 'e' doesn't make it out of the inner comprehension. And you're right about the regular expression being the right solution. But I was curious about fixing the comprehension before moving on...

Comment: @KentH I forgot to add `e` to the output of the genexp. Try again

Answer (score 2):

Use a generator with a normal loop to perform this sort of task which needs state:

```
def errsplit(err):
    for e in err.splitlines():
        errindex = e.find('error:')
        if errindex > -1: yield e[errindex:]
```

If you need this as a list, just do `list(errsplit(err))`.

List comprehensions's aren't really intended to deal with stored state, and attempts to use stored state in them can get clunky.

That said, note that a regex might better, as suggested by @JBernardo.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried JBernardo's solutions but what really worked for me was:

```
[errstr[i:] for i,errstr in
 ((e.find('error:'), e) for e in err.splitlines())
 if i != -1]
```

Comment: Why stick with this oneliner which you can't fit on one line, and which is complex to read?

Comment: I've only fixed the other version presented by JBernardo which was not actually working ;)